# Is redirect type not supported by Safari Browser in declarativeNetRequest rules?

Tags: redirect, google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-extension

I am trying to write a URL-redirection safari web extension.

manifest.json

```
"declarative_net_request": {
        "rule_resources": [
            {
                "id": "ruleset",
                "enabled": true,
                "path": "rules.json"
            }
        ]
    },
 "permissions": [
        "declarativeNetRequest",
        "webNavigation"
    ]
}
```

rules.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "redirect",
            "redirect": {
                "regexSubstitution": "https://example.com/"
            }
        },
        "condition": {
            "regexFilter": "http://*/",
            "resourceTypes": [
                "main_frame"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Expectation - any search should redirect to example.com

Getting this error `Non-fatal issue: Rule with id 1 is invalid. redirect is not a supported action type.`

The same code works fine in chrome as a chrome extension, giving error in safari browser only.

Is redirect not supported by safari? If no, what other options do i have to achieve it?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like the answer is already apparent  - `redirect is not a supported action type` - I share your frustration

Comment: @justinw any suggestions, how can i do url redirects for safari then? Tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71158725/webnavigate-doesnt-work-in-safari-extension-with-tabs-update

Comment: I am not sure if you posted a similar question in the Apple forums, but as mentioned there, you could use `browser.webRequest` (not supported for iOS) or `browser.tabs.update`, or simply build the functionality into a content script. It might not have great ux but it can get the job done.

Comment: `browser.webRequest` requires blocking and blocking webRequest is not supported in Safari Web Extensions - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650840 .

Don't want to embed in content-script, so I tried `tabs.update` and faced this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219177/why-tabs-update-doesnt-work-in-safari-if-url-filters-are-added. Can you please take a look at this question?

Answer (score 1):

I was just researching this and found this note in [Webkit's blog](https://webkit.org/blog/12193/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-139/) from 6 months ago.

> Added support for the `redirect` rule type in `declarativeNetRequest`,
> which requires host permissions to be granted for the host of the URL
> being redirected

https://webkit.org/blog/12193/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-139/

I tried to get redirect working on the latest beta iOS16 and GOT SOMETHING WORKING... still testing...

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible with the recent ios releases. `redirect` rule has been [available since Safari 15.4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/blocking_content_with_your_safari_web_extension), and `regexSubsitution` has been [added in Safari 17](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-17-release-notes).

Your code will need to be modified slightly. To use `redirect` rule, you need to have the permission `"declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"` instead of `"declarativeNetRequest"`. [Host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/declare-permissions) is also supposed to be needed, like such: `"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]` (although at the time of writing, redirect works without it on iphones).

Also, `"http://*/"` is not a regex pattern but a glob pattern, so you may need to change it to `"url_filter"` instead of `"regex_filter"`.

Sidenote: `redirect` rule (or perhaps declarativeNetRequest as a whole) may not be supported on iphone simulators. I haven't managed to get it work on the simulator.